# How to customize language in external file in winforms

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, multilingual

I have a Winforms .NET 3.5 application and I need to make it multi-language. Using resources is not a valid solution for me, as I need that the final customer may modify the strings to customize a language or to translate the software to other languages.

Does anyone know any tool or technique to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I have developed applications with the translations in the database, I think this is your best solution, you just have to pay close attention to the cache as going to the database for each word its not a good idea.

Just make sure to setup cache for a long time and to reset it each time you change a word for a language.